# Positive averages of different tabs

Tags: excel, tabs, excel-formula, average

I have weather information of a lot of weather stations over 5 years. There is one file for each station, for each year, and each year is divided in 12 tabs; one for each month. The measuring was done every 10 minutes so there is a huge number of data (imagine one measurement every 10 minutes of each month). Im trying to make an average of the weather information of each month of only positive numbers with the function =averageif(range,">0",range) on another tab, say one after the month "December". Do you know how to program that function so that it starts from the cell B2 to the last value of that column when working on another tab, not on the tab that has the values?

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B1` is just a header of text your equation will ignore the text and calculate everything else.  Applying the formula from another tab is straight forward.  On the tab you want the equation select a cell and enter the equal sign `=` then click the tab you want and select the column you want.  Excel will do everything else.

Here is what it should look like:

```
=AVERAGEIF(Sheet1!B:B,">0",Sheet1!B:B)
```

My test data look like this:

[image]

---

Result on the other tab looks like this:

[image]

---

***EDIT***

If your header row is a number that messes up the average you can ignore the first row like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(Sheet1!B2:OFFSET(Sheet1!B2,COUNT(Sheet1!B:B),0),">0",Sheet1!B2:OFFSET(Sheet1!B2,COUNT(Sheet1!B:B),0))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Portland Runner, maybe I have to explain a little better. Im doing at the moment exactly that, Im looking for a way to automate the formula, so that it finds the last value on the Column B by itself. That way I would be able to copy paste the formula for every file.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused about what you want then.  `Sheet1!B:B` will automatically find the last value in column... or my last equation with `Sheet1!B2:OFFSET(Sheet1!B2,COUNT(Sheet1!B:B),0)` will do it a slightly different way but both answers find the last value.  What exactly do you want to automate?